# DRY layouts and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user profile page with a sidebar. I need to create more pages within the profile. For example, edit password, edit profile information, statistics, purchase history list, etc. I'm not sure how to proceed while keeping things DRY. I'm trying to get everything to be the exact same except the main content. While going through some tutorials I came across `yield` but it was mostly used in the `application.html.erb` to render navigation, footer, etc. I don't understand how to use it for "sub-views".

The way I'm doing it right now seems wrong.

Routes:

```
  as :user do
    # Routes to change password of signed in user
    get 'user/password' => 'users/registrations#edit_password', as: 'edit_password'

    # Routes to change user profile information of signed in users
    get 'user/profile' => 'users/registrations#edit_profile', as: 'user_profile'
  end
```

Views:

`views\users\show.html.erb`:

`views\users\registrations\edit_profile.html.erb`:

`views\users\registrations\edit_password.html.erb`:

All contain this 1 line

```
            <%= render 'users/shared/profile' %>
```

`views\users\shared\profile`:

```
            <%= render 'users/profile/sidebar' %>

            <!-- Display Profile or Password based on route -->
            <% if current_page?(user_path current_user) %>
                <!-- User Profile -->
                <%=render 'users/profile/adminPanels' %>
            <% elsif current_page?(edit_password_path) %>
                <!-- Password Reset -->
                <%=render 'passwordForm' %>
            <% else %>
                <!-- Profile Edit -->
                <%= render 'users/registrations/profileForm' %>
            <% end %>
```

Basically what I wanted to do is keep all the surrounding layout but change the rendered content. Now that I need to add more, extending this if statement really seems like the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is definitely not the way to go, but it's good that you recognize that so no worries. As you guessed, the way to do this involves using layouts and `yield`. You can read about yield in [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).

While you can have a layouts like `application.rb` that your entire Rails app uses by default, you can also define layouts nested within this layout. This is described in the same Rails guide as above, [towards the bottom](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).

This way, the stuff that is the same for your entire application is defined in the `application` layout, the stuff that is same for everything that is a user profile is defined in the `users` layout, and the stuff that is specific to each view is defined in there.

*Side note:* as the `users` layout is in the `layouts` folder, I acted as though you moved the `_sidebar` partial there as well since it is really a partial that belongs to the layout and should be near it.

**views/layouts/users.html.erb**

```
<%= render '_sidebar' %>
<%= yield :users_content %>
<%= render template: 'layouts/application' %>
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :users_content do %>
  put the view code specific to users/show here
<% end %>
```

**views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :users_content do %>
  put the view code specific to editing a user registration here
<% end %>
```

etc.

The only thing that you may have issue with is that Rails is using the name of the controller to match the nested `users` layout and that may break for the `registrations` stuff if that's a different controller. You can fix that by explicitly calling `render template: 'layouts/users'` inside of those controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

From what code snippet you've provided, the DRYest way would be to move
`<%=render 'users/profile/adminPanels' %>`
directly to the `show.html.erb` page after rendering `shared/profile`. Same thing for other views.